# How to conditionally change datagrid rows background color?

Tags: react-admin

Depends on the the source (record's) field value (E.g. status column is 'active') I want to make the row background certain color in Datagrid. How do I do that? Thank you for any sample code to do that!

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the datagrid row style (applied to the `<tr>` element) based on the record, thanks to the `rowStyle` prop, which expects a function.

For instance, this allows to apply a custom background to the entire row if one value of the record - like its number of views - passes a certain threshold.

```
const postRowStyle = (record, index) => ({
    backgroundColor: record.nb_views >= 500 ? '#efe' : 'white',
});
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowStyle={postRowStyle}>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

This is documented in [The React-admin Datagrid Documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#row-style-function).

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: how do i change text color of a cell based on the condition ?